# PDOException could not find driver with postgresql 10

Tags: php, postgresql

This my php.ini:

[image: php.ini]

Why does my server on localhost error with 'could not find driver' even though I already opened the ';' in pdo_psql?

Comment: I would check your [php info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) and see if it's listed there.  Also posible you are not using a correct [DSN](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.connection.php).

Comment: As suggested in the comments of your php.ini file, have you checked or set the correct *extension_dir* directive?

Comment: Please post the contents of your php.ini file instead of an image.